# Añadir carácter encima de una columna en awk

Tags: shell, awk

¿Es posible añadir una letra encima de una columna determinada de un archivo mediante `awk` en Linux?

Así, dado este fichero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Querría que quedara de la siguiente manera:

[image: .]

Comment: Detalla un poco mas, pero `awk` tiene la funcionalidad de ejecutar algo **al inicio del script**, con el *patron* `BEGIN`. Busca por ahí.

Comment: Perdona, ya he editado la pregunta con imágenes de lo que querría hacer

Comment: De todos modos, sería conveniente que pegaras el contenido de las imágenes. De esta manera podremos copiar su contenido.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que das una captura de pantalla que no se puede copiar, creo yo el fichero. Supongamos que tenemos este texto:

```
$ cat fich
**********TOTAL********
sem1 140 165 165 165 160
sem2 210 210 200 200 225
```

Con `awk` se pueden hacer virguerías. Por ejemplo, le podemos decir que escriba algo cuando esté leyendo la segunda línea:

```
$ awk 'NR==2 {print "L", "M", "X", "J", "V"}1' fich
**********TOTAL********
L M X J V
sem1 140 165 165 165 160
sem2 210 210 200 200 225
```

Esto dice: cuando el número de registro sea 2 (en este caso, cuando leamos la segunda línea), escribe la cadena "L M X J V". Después, con `1` lanzamos la acción por defecto de `awk`, consistente en imprimir la línea actual.

Como el formato queda un poco feo, podemos utilizar [modificadores de formato de printf()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers):

```
$ awk 'NR==2 {printf "%5s %5s %5s %5s %5s\n", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V"}1' fich
**********TOTAL********
    L     M     X     J     V
sem1 140 165 165 165 160
sem2 210 210 200 200 225
```

Pero como queda algo repetitivo, ¿qué tal si pasamos los valores por variable y lo construimos dinámicamente?

```
awk -v dias="L M X J V" '
    BEGIN{n=split(dias, dias_arr)} 
    NR==2 {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
              printf "%5s ", dias_arr[i]
           print ""}
    1' fich
```

Y si me apuras, incluso podemos hacer [que los modificadores de printf() sean dinámicos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408074/1983854):

```
awk -v dias="L M X J V" -v espacio=5 '
    BEGIN{n=split(dias, dias_arr)} 
    NR==2 {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
              printf "%*s ", espacio, dias_arr[i]
           print ""}
    1' fich
```

Con tu fichero:

```
$ awk -v dias="L M X J V" -v espacio=5 'BEGIN{n=split(dias, dias_arr)} NR==2 {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%*s ", espacio, dias_arr[i]; print ""}1' fich
**********TOTAL********
    L     M     X     J     V 
sem1 140 165 165 165 160
sem2 210 210 200 200 225
```